# Hide secondary account in Android Market

Tags: google-play-store, google-account

I have a problem with my android phone: I have two Gmail accounts.
The first on is my main account, with everything synchronized on my Android phone (mails, contacts, calendar, apps, ...). The other account is only for emails, and as such I've set it up to ONLY synchronize the mails (and only the mails!), BUT this address shows up in the Android Market app nevertheless. To make matters worse, this secondary address seems to be always chosen by default when I launch the Market app, and I also receive notifications for some apps.

So my question is this: Is it possible to only have the main account showing in the Market app, while still having mail synchronization enabled for other accounts?

Thank you very much

Comment: If you press the Menu button and choose the account you want, does it still default to the account you don't want after restarting the Market?

Comment: Yes it does, and there is no option to select one over the other, or even delete an account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove the account that it "defaults" to and try to re-add the account. I think there is some type of bug in the newer version of the market because I have the same issue from time to time. it is not the "default" account, and I have like 8 accounts on the device (all google accounts) but it always wants to use this one.

I found that it "fixes", but usually only temporarily, if I go in to the Application Settings and clear the data for the market app.